# Beginner runner/jogger heart rate question

Tags: running, cardio, heart-rate, jogging, heart-rate-monitor

I am an it guy 220 lbs 6ft1 35 years old. With chest strap measurement my maximum heart rate is around 192 bpm. (Did warmup and 3 minutes thread mill intervals to measure)

For a long period of time, my spare time for gym was very poor. I did 15 mins @ 5.4mph with 5 minutes cooldown twice a week. No other exercise. At work I mostly sit. My background has a family heart disease and I fell on my chest more than 1 year ago (hospital test had everything normal).

I did physical last week: Resting heart rate 65 to 80. Blood pressure normal. EKG tested normal.

Every since I brought the heart monitor I encountered huge problem with heart rate. When normally walking at 3.8 mph for 5 mins bpm is 115.

When jogging at 4.3 mph for 5-7 mins bpm reaches a whopping 152 bpm.

I need some advice as good advice is not cheap in my area (cardiologist).

Could this be a blood cloth problem? Or because having too much fat in the chest area? (pressing on blood vessels) I am trying to gauge how urgent to see the doc again. Or this is something like normal for runners? I am by no means worried, its just in today's busy world I can barely book 1 open meeting next week and I also have a fully booked week after. I have to balance my work week time between family, money and health.

So just wondering if this wierd spike is normal for somebody with my background.

ps: I tried breathing less through the nose, sometimes that affects bpm. When doing 20mins @ 5.4 mph or more, I need 10 mins cooldown otherwise i get left year tinnitus/pressure for ~15mins. I do not know if ps sections details are relevant.

Comment: I'm really sorry that you don't have access to medical care in your country, however getting it over the internet on a site where random strangers can answer is not a solution. You have some weird theories on what you might have, I wonder if you have a reason to come up with this stuff.

Comment: Hi tekrunner2k, welcome to Fitness.SE. Unfortunately, general medical questions are off-topic here. As Raditz mentioned, it is very hard to diagnose over the internet. You can check out https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/what-heart-rate-can-a-beginner-runner-expect?rq=1 or https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5263/is-this-heart-rate-too-high-for-a-beginner-runner?rq=. If you search `[running] "heart-rate" is:question` there are quite a few similar questions that may help.

Comment: I understand good advice is not cheap, but cheap advice is not necessarily good. What is the cost of your life? Go see the doctor. And while you are there, ask him about safely starting an exercise regimen. (For instance, maximal HR treadmill testing is usually done in a clinic with doctors and emergency equipment near at had, just in case).