# Maximum heart rate during a 5k or 10k run

Tags: running

Just bought a running watch and went for a 5k run and then the other day for a 10k run. There is a range of a heart rate that is originally set up at 75 bpm at lower end and 175 bpm at higher end.

Now, I wonder what is the 'normal' maximum heart rate while running??? My watch warned me with a signal that my heart is beating above 175 (as it is set to that value which I can change). Actually, the max heart rate I had was 183. Is that normal during a run or not? Am I in danger while runing at that heart rate? Most of the time during my runs my heart rate was around 170 to 177. But at some points it went above to the max of 184 as I said. Should I be worried?

Thanks all for help!

Comment: Hi; welcome to the site.  This isn't a question that would be appropriate here, but I'll move it to our sister site [fitness.se] where it may be more appropriate.

Comment: See these questions: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15736/is-my-heart-rate-too-high-to-run or https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/what-heart-rate-can-a-beginner-runner-expect?rq=1 or https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15736/is-my-heart-rate-too-high-to-run?rq=1.

Comment: The fact that you watch has shonw you 175 bpm doesn't mean that it was actually so. I have Garmin, and from time to time it 'spins' totally.

Comment: Which inspired me to ask about https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/43529/how-reliable-are-heart-rate-data-from-smart-watches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some dispute over heart rate ranges and what is dangerous and what is okay. Personally, I think that anything ranging 180 is a good high-intensity/max effort heart rate. While I was in my running phase, I would often push up to 200ish during HIIT, but some may feel as though that is not safe. Assuming you are in your 20's, a heart rate between 170-185 is good anaerobic activity, basically high-intensity.

As you run more, your body will become accustomed to running and that type of cardio, as well as your heart. You should notice that your heart rates decrease over time as your heart gets stronger.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am actually in early 40s. I don't run regularly but ocassionally, mostly before and after the summer. So, in general you think anything below 200 is safe? I didn't feel any problems while running at 183 which was just for a short period of time during my run as most of my run time was btwn 170 and 177. Basically, I just wanted to know if it is safe to continue to run if my heart rate goes above 180.

Comment: @C.Felipe Alright! Again, this is a very opinionated topic, but I would argue that 180ish as a peak heart rate is not bad at all. In fact I think there are points during exercise where we SHOULD exercise that much in order to get better and stronger. If we aren't pushing parts of our body to the max, progress will be a lot slower. All in all, yes, it is something to monitor but not be overly worried about.

Comment: Thanks for reply @ThatOneNerdyBoy Good to hear that. I wonder what heart rate other people have during their runs? Do you know yours?

Comment: @C.Felipe When I did long-distance running in my teens I would generally average 160-170, however, I was quite light and built for running. Now I am 19, 6'5, and 105kg, so I average 180 during runs now, often getting peaks above 190. But my style of running is more push myself to the limits. I don't stop when I feel like I am getting tired, I typically go for 10-15 more minutes after that time.

Comment: You won't know your max unless you do a maximum HR test on a treadmill monitored by a doc. Don't go by 220-age, that has long been debunked. If you did not feel dizzy, have pain/flutters/weird sensations in the chest, probably fine. Anecdotal N=1, I am 53, and I regularly hit over 200 during high intensity (Hill sprints, HIIT, etc).

Comment: Thanks for valuable info @JohnP

Answer (score 2):

I am 73 years old. Have been running from high school. 29 marathons, including the last March LA marathon at the height of worldwide spread of Covid 19.

Everyone is different. It could be that heartbeat is not the first cause for concern. As we know it is heart- longs- vascular and blood composition.

I run 9-10 miles 6 days a week.
My heartbeat goes above 195 when i run uphill for 1o-15 minutes. I push myself to pant. It may not be safe fore some.

For me muscle injury is first cause for concern. Because healing at my age takes time. So I listen to my muscles carefully.

Comment: Wow! Huge respect. Thanks for sharing your exerience here with us. I am not concerned but rather wanted to know if my heart rate is in normal range. I didn't feel any problems while it was at 183. Hope you can do next marathon soon to make that number round to 30. And many more in the future!